# wifstream.tellg() advancing position in the stream?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, iostream

I've been doing some basic file manipulations with iostreams in Visual Studio 2015 and noticed this weird behavior.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::wifstream stream("example.txt");
    //std::ifstream stream("example.txt");
    //std::wstringstream stream(L"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz");

    std::wcout << (char)stream.peek() << "\n"; // a
    stream.tellg();
    std::wcout << (char)stream.peek() << "\n"; // b
    stream.tellg();
    std::wcout << (char)stream.peek() << "\n"; // c
    stream.tellg();
    std::wcout << (char)stream.peek() << "\n"; // d
    stream.tellg();
    std::wcout << (char)stream.peek() << "\n"; // e
    stream.tellg();
    std::wcout << (char)stream.peek() << "\n"; // f
    stream.tellg();
    std::wcout << (char)stream.peek() << "\n"; // g
    stream.tellg();
}
```

example.txt contains:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz
```

It seems like `stream.tellg()` advances the stream's current character by one. This happens only for `std::wifstream`. `std::ifstream` and `std::wstringstream` seem not to be affected.

Is this a bug in visual studio stl implementation?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is similar with [wifstream/wfstream implementation bug in Visual C++ 2010](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/594816/wifstream-wfstream-implementation-bug-in-visual-c-2010).

As Stephan said:

> C++ Standard does not provide behavior guarantees when calling tellg()
>   on a file opened in text mode.

I guess that's the cause.